# Add missing value of pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
[{'Date': Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'),'Sex':'M', 'Value':11, 'Target':5, 'A':48},
{'Date': Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'),'Sex':'F', 'Value':25, 'Target':7, 'A':20},
{'Date': Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00'),'Sex':'M', 'Value':45, 'Target':6, 'A':20},
{'Date': Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00'),'Sex':'F', 'Value':5, 'Target':2, 'A':16},
{'Date': Timestamp('2023-01-20 00:00:00'),'Sex':'M', 'Value':10, 'Target':8, 'A':30}]
{'Date': Timestamp('2023-01-20 00:00:00'),'Sex':'M', 'Value':1, 'Target':18, 'A':3}]
```

```
Date    Sex Value   Target  A
0   2023-01-01  M   11  5   48
1   2023-01-01  F   25  7   20
2   2023-01-10  M   45  6   20
3   2023-01-10  F   5   2   16
4   2023-01-20  M   10  8   30
5   2023-01-20  M   1   18  3
```

And like to fill up the missing Date: 2023-01-20 Sex: F as 0 to Value, Target and A.
Result:

```
Date    Sex Value   Target  A
0   2023-01-01  M   11  5   48
1   2023-01-01  F   25  7   20
2   2023-01-10  M   45  6   20
3   2023-01-10  F   5   2   16
4   2023-01-20  M   10  8   30
5   2023-01-20  M   1   18  3
6   2023-01-20  F   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a double [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), once to combine the dates and M/F, then to add the missing combinations to the original data.

```
out = (df[['Date']]
 .drop_duplicates()
 .merge(pd.Series(['M', 'F'], name='Sex'), how='cross')
 .merge(df, how='left').fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
)
```

Alternatively, using `janitor`'s [`complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete):

```
import janitor

out = df.complete('Date', {'Sex': ['M', 'F']}, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
        Date Sex  Value  Target   A
0 2023-01-01   M     11       5  48
1 2023-01-01   F     25       7  20
2 2023-01-10   M     45       6  20
3 2023-01-10   F      5       2  16
4 2023-01-20   M     10       8  30
5 2023-01-20   M      1      18   3
6 2023-01-20   F      0       0   0
```

Another option is to build a new dataframe and run an outer/left merge (similar to what [`complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) does internally) :

```py
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Date.unique(), 
                                    df.Sex.unique()], 
                                    names = ['Date', 'Sex'])
index = pd.DataFrame([], index = index)
index.merge(df, on=['Date','Sex'],how='left').fillna(0)
        Date Sex  Value  Target     A
0 2023-01-01   M   11.0     5.0  48.0
1 2023-01-01   F   25.0     7.0  20.0
2 2023-01-10   M   45.0     6.0  20.0
3 2023-01-10   F    5.0     2.0  16.0
4 2023-01-20   M   10.0     8.0  30.0
5 2023-01-20   M    1.0    18.0   3.0
6 2023-01-20   F    0.0     0.0   0.0
```

Comment: @sammywemmy I had used explicitly a dictionary in case M/F might be missing in the original data. Btw `df.complete('Date','Sex', fill_value=0)` gives me an error (`TypeError: DatetimeArray data type is not supported in 'expand_grid'.`).

Comment: My apologies @mozway. What version of pandas pls triggers this error? What version of pyjanitor?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct new index, reindex the dataframe with default fill_value and reset the index back:

```py
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df.Date.unique(), df.Sex.unique()], names=["Date", "Sex"]
)
df = df.set_index(["Date", "Sex"]).reindex(new_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Date Sex  Value  Target   A
0 2023-01-01   M     11       5  48
1 2023-01-01   F     25       7  20
2 2023-01-10   M     45       6  20
3 2023-01-10   F      5       2  16
4 2023-01-20   M     10       8  30
5 2023-01-20   F      0       0   0
```

Comment: That's a very good answer. But can't handle non unique multi-index. I have edited the df. @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 1):

```
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
[df['Date'].unique(), df['Sex'].unique()], names=["Date", "Sex"]
)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=new_idx).reset_index()

df2 = pd.merge(df.set_index(["Date", "Sex"]),df1.set_index(["Date", 
"Sex"]), how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()
df2.fillna(0)

print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
Date    Sex Value   Target  A
0   2023-01-01  F   25.0    7.0 75.0
1   2023-01-01  M   11.0    5.0 90.0
2   2023-01-10  F   5.0     2.0 95.0
3   2023-01-10  M   45.0    6.0 36.0
4   2023-01-20  F   0       0   0
5   2023-01-20  M   10.0    8.0 43.0
6   2023-01-20  M   1.0    18.0  3.0
```